# Creating variable in as raw_input, syntax error

Tags: python

```
driver_name = print(raw_input('What is your name?: '))
```

I figured that this might create something like a console input to enter name, but I was wrong and it's returning a `SyntaxError`. I tried with and without the parentheses, to no avail.

Comment: print is not able to be assigned to anything in python 2

Comment: Even if it could be, like in Python 3, `print` always returns `None`...

Answer (score 1):

```
driver_name = raw_input("Your Name")
print driver_name
```

in python2 you cannot assign print to anything as it is a statement instead of an expression

```
x=print("anything")
```

is always a syntax error in python2

you could do something like

```
from __future__ import print_statement
x = print(raw_input("whatever")) #as mentioned you will always get None as the value
```

if you really really wanted to you could do something like

```
def print_and_return(value):
    print value
    return value

driver_name = print_and_return(raw_input("Name?"))
```

Comment: In later versions of Python 2 you can do `from __future__ import print_function` and then it becomes syntactically valid, but even then, the return value of `print` is `None` so the input value would be lost.

Comment: you could potentially do some hackery to make it work ... but probably not great

Comment: Yeah, you could redefine `print` so it returns whatever it prints... which would mean a complete reimplementation of every aspect of `print` except that it builds a string.

Answer (score 1):

Set `driver_name = raw_input('What is your name?')` and then `print driver_name`